# Automatic import of photos when connecting a camera

Tags: windows-10

When connected to Win 7, a simple window was opened where, with the push of a button, all new photos were imported.
In Win 10 You have to open a folder, click on the device, select the import.
How is it possible and is it possible to make it automatic? Do not need the bells and whistles. To simply import all new photos from the device into the same folder? Can you write a * .bat for these purposes and a task manager?
I really was tortured. I repeat these simple steps 50 times a day. It takes a lot of time.
What is in Win 10 is not very convenient.
Sorry, I use a translator.